# Formatting output with spaces in C

Tags: c, string, string-formatting

Let's supppose I have a variable with numeric value and I want to print it  using 10 characters like the following: `XXX XXXX XXX XXXX`. So, for example, the number 10 would be printed as `000 0000 000 0010`.

The closest I got in a straightforward way is using, for instance:

```
int value = 10;

printf("%010D", value);
```

However it produces, obviously:

```
0000000010
```

Does anyone know if there's any built-in function that could output

```
000 0000 000 0010
```

or it'd be necessary to implement one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no easy way to achieve that with a built-in function. You might be able to create a funky locale that would create a format like that (thousands grouping character is a space, and the sequence '\4\3\4\3' for the grouping sequence), but even you'd need a non-standard function to format the string according to that locale.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First note that a 32-bit int has a max value of 2,147,483,647.  So a 14 digit number is impossible (except with at least 4 leading zeros).  You'd need a 64-bit `long long int` to get 14 non-zero digits.

There is no simple library call that allows it, but making this happen is not hard. One way is to split the value with integer math.  Another is by splitting a string:

```
int main(void) {

  long long int value = 12345678901234;

  // by string splitting...
  char buf[32];
  sprintf(buf, "%014lld", value);
  printf("%.3s %.4s %.3s %.4s\n", buf, buf + 3, buf + 7, buf + 10);

  // by integer modular arithmetic...
  unsigned v0 = (unsigned)(value % 10000);
  value /= 10000;
  unsigned v1 = (unsigned)(value % 1000);
  value /= 1000;
  unsigned v2 = (unsigned)(value % 10000);
  value /= 10000;
  unsigned v3 = (unsigned)value;
  printf("%03u %04u %03u %04u\n", v3, v2, v1, v0);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! I wanted to avoid to do much calculation, so I liked most the string splitting. I didn't know the sprintf function, actually. Thanks for the response!